# password validation form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, passwords

I'm new to rails and i want to make a signup login and forget password functionality from scratch so i have been following railscast 250 and 274 episodes..so the problem is, the validations on password and password confirmation fields are working fine on signup form but on the reset password form those validations are not working at all..code is below

model:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :signup_token
      attr_accessor :password
      before_save :encrypt_password
      before_create {generate_token(:auth_token)}
      before_create {generate_token(:signup_token)}
      validates :password, length: {minimum: 8}, confirmation: true, presence: true,:on       => :create
      validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
      validates :email, format: {with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i, message: "not valid"}

      def generate_token(column)
        begin
          self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64         
        end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
      end

      def self.authenticate(email, password)
        user = find_by_email(email)
        if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt) && user.active == true
          user
        else
          nil
        end
     end

     def encrypt_password
       if password.present?
         self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
         self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
       end
     end

      def send_password_reset
        generate_token(:password_reset_token)
        self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
        save!
        UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
      end
    end
```

password_resets_controller:

```
    class PasswordResetsController < ApplicationController
      def new
      end

      def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    user.send_password_reset if user
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Email sent with password reset instructions."
      end

      def edit
    @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
      end

      def update
        @user = User.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
        if @user.password_reset_sent_at < 2.hours.ago
          redirect_to new_password_reset_path, :alert => "Password reset has expired."
        elsif @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset."
        else
          render :edit
        end
      end
     end
```

and views under password reset are
new.html.erb:

```
    <h1>Reset Password</h1>

    <%= form_tag password_resets_path, :method => :post do %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :email %>
        <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions"><%= submit_tag "Reset Password" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

edit.html.erb:

```
    <h1>Reset Password</h1>

    <%= form_for @user, :url => password_reset_path(params[:id]) do |f| %>
      <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div class="error_messages">
          <h2>Form is invalid</h2>
          <ul>
            <% for message in @user.errors.full_messages %>
              <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Update Password" %></div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: change `validates :password, length: {minimum: 8}, confirmation: true, presence: true,:on => :create` to validates :password, length: {minimum: 8}, confirmation: true, presence: true,:on => [:create, :update] but I think this will also trigger if you update user records on non-password fields too

Comment: @j03w by adding :on=>[:create, :update] to validation its showing syntax error in PasswordResetsController#create whenever i'm clicking on "Reset Password" button and if i simply remove ":on" condition it shows following error: "Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters), Password can't be blank"

Comment: ah sorry my bad… let me see for a sec

Comment: I think you will have to use the same approach as `Devise` for this. Add this method to your user: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L53-L55

and instead of `:on => :create` you do `:if => :password_required?` like in Devise…

Comment: remove :on => :create validations by default it will take on create and update

Comment: @priyankaUkirde already tried that, as i mentioned in my previous comment..as soon as i enter email address in "new.html.erb" and hit reset button it shows "Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters), Password can't be blank"